# Media queries won't work in LENSA ( Wordpress theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to edit a couple things in the media queries of [LENSA](http://colorlabsproject.com/themes/lensa/), a Wordpress theme. My edits do not work.

For example, I want to change this class:

```
.left {
    width: 70%; 
    float: left;
}
```

So I write it like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px){
    .left {
        width: 100%; 
        float: none;
    }
 }
```

There is no change when the screen is 480px....

Site: [www.karaokesharksf.com](http://www.karaokesharksf.com)

Comment: where is the .left class on what part of the page? when i go there i see dont see it in the DOM.. what page is it on?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `@media` statement might be over-complicating it. Why not try just this?

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
    .left {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
}
```